# Sound doesnt work, after installing GPU Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, gpu

I had a Radeon 4670 that I replaced, with an Nvidea GeForce gtx460. 
Now My sound doesn't work. I figure it was a driver issue, so I installed the manufacturers recommended driver, but it still doesn't work. 
What can I do to get audio working on my computer again?

Here's what `lshw` says about my audio device:

```
#lshw
...
*-multimedia
     description: Audio device
     product: MCP61 High Definition Audio
     vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
     physical id: 5
     bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
     version: a2
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 66MHz
     capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
     resources: irq:23 memory:fe028000-fe02bfff
```

Comment: can you post me the output of `lshw -c sound`? It is possible that you have two different drivers installed. ATI and Nvidia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a Terminal and type in `alsamixer`

Use your arrow keys to navigate through the menu... To Select your sound card press `F6`. A new window should pop up. Select the new sound card and press enter.

After that you should be able to enjoy your music again :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the installation of my new GPU was not related. 
I had sound muted in lightdm, which makes sound unavailable in the logged in session of ubuntu.

I believe this is a bug specifically related to lightdm. Once logged in, you have no ability to change the setting (mute). or rather unchecking mute, the system remains muted.